# How to create floating point validation with two decimals in Yii2?

Tags: yii2-basic-app

I have tried creating a validation for a field which stores unit price of a product, I come across validation showing how to check for integer, but I can't found one for floating point number something with a format like `2032.95` in **YII2**. Thanks in advance.

*

> After Abilay instructions I tried

- [['quantity','round_off'],'number','numberPattern'=>'[-+]?[0-9]*.[0-9]+|[0-9]+'],

but it shows error in console.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think, redefining of [numberPattern](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-numbervalidator.html#$numberPattern-detail) of NumberValidator class will help in your case.

---

If you use AJAX Validator on your form:

1. In Model:
       `[['quantity','round_off'], 'number',
   'numberPattern' => '/^\d+(.\d{1,2})?$/'],`
2. In View:
   Ensure that you enabled AJAX Validation when created form
       `$form = ActiveForm::begin([
       'id' => 'my-form',
       'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
   ]);`

   and change field to default input
       `$form->field($model, 'quantity')`
3. In Controller:
   Include files:
       `use yii\web\Response;
    use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;`

   Past this code at the beginning of action, after
       `$model` is loaded or created
       `if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
       Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
           return ActiveForm::validate($model);
   }`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I tried like `[['quantity','round_off'],'number','numberPattern'=>'[-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+'],` in the rules, if I give text it says it should be numberbut I am getting some error in the firebug.