# Yii2 how to set decimal rule in model

Tags: model, yii2, decimal, yii2-advanced-app

I have a model

```
<?php

namespace common\models;

use Yii;

/**
* This is the model class for table "new_val".
*
* @property integer $id
* @property string $avg
* @property string $sd
*/
class NewVal extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'new_val';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['avg', 'sd'], 'double'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'avg' => 'Avg',
        'sd' => 'Sd',
    ];
}
}
```

In my `DB` I have set the values of `avg` and `sd` as a decimal. So I want to save a decimal value in it.

I have tried to search the method but couldn't find a good solution. I have tried to set `float` and `double` in my rules. But `float` gives me an exception and `double` convert my entered decimal number to round number i.e. If I have entered `15.5` then it will be round off to `16`.

How can I set my rule with a decimal number?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How did you created this decimal column?

Comment: I think this is the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33123647/how-to-create-floating-point-validation-with-two-decimals-in-yii2 but try different pattern if that doesnt suit you

Answer (score 2):

try [`validator number`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#number) but according to the framework it is the same as `double`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['avg', 'sd'], 'number'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

hi use number in your rule , 
round of the number is not about yii if you have number like 16.66677777777777777
and your field in mysql don't have enough space that round it to prevent this use

```
floor(your_number * 100) / 100
```